# 404 page when run as web application project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I want to create a basic Google Web Application project and i get an 404 Page not found error. 
I followed several tutorials and what i do is this:

Open eclipse - File - New - Other - Web Application Project (under Google) - name it - (it doesn't matter if i check "Use GWT" or not the result is the same - Finish.

Right now i have a newly created web application project, so i can test it in localhost. I right click it, run as - web application project (with google icon). After it finishes in my console i have this:

> Mar 22, 2017 10:13:58 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
>   INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
>   Mar 22, 2017 10:13:58 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
>   INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
>   Mar 22, 2017 10:13:58 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
>   INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
>   Mar 22, 2017 12:13:58 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
>   INFO: Dev App Server is now running

I open Chrome and go to localhost and i get:

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>
> Problem accessing /. 
>   Reason:
>   NOT_FOUND
>
> Powered by Jetty://

I must specify that i am deploying behind a proxy server. I tried also to run it without proxy, same result. All my settings are correct, because if i create a Dynamic Web Project and i deploy it on a Tomcat server, that one works fine.

Comment: What URL do you try to open? Try `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: That's the one i tried.

Comment: I also, found the solution. My Java facet was 1.8. It needed to be 1.7.

Comment: @DanielGrosu: mention the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is this. Check your Java facet. It has to be 1.7. Mine was 1.8.

Thank you.